# how to adjust color gradient to create a shiny or glossy button using css?

Tags: html, css, button, gradient

Is there any formula or systematic rules to create those gradients, rather than trying numerous times?  There are good shiny/glossy button demos via google but the gradient colors they use are just for specific color.

Comment: Umm... Did you accidentally click "submit" in the middle of your question? `:)`

Comment: Tried to edit, but I don't know why that pesky 'I' showed up in the post but not in the preview and edit window.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Thanks Danny that's a very helpful tool and can save a lot of time.